# selenium RC ,WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(serverUrl), capability);

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

See this code:

```
String serverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub";

DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(serverUrl), capability);
```

When a request comes in, it will be create new instance, which will take between 2 and 4 seconds. For me, this is too long. How can I make it faster?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're actually doing? You should reuse the WebDriver as much as possible. Continually creating them will destroy performance.

Comment: I use selenium Grid to screenshot ,so every time the request come in,it will be create WebDriver instance(when WebDriver was instance,it will be start a browser),so,I want to resuse this browser.this is my question.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing the right thing .You can increase number of nodes and browsers that will help in executing all of your tests in less time .

Comment: I  start  Hub use this:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.49.1.jar -role hub -maxSession 400

start node use this:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.49.1.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=2.8,maxInstances=400,platform=LINUX .but every time,instance a webDriver it will be spent 2 seconds,I want to reduce the time.